# Usage of <address> tag in HTML: copyright or webmaster?

Tags: html, microformats, hcard

On the footer of my client’s website I have his address and copyright notice, and under there is the address of the webmaster.

With both I will use the hCard microformat.

With which of them I should use the `<address>` tag?

Answer (score 5):

As per the HTML5 spec:

> The `address` element represents the contact information for its nearest `article` or `body` element ancestor. If that is the `body` element, then the contact information applies to the document as a whole.
>
> http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/sections.html#the-address-element

So I guess both addresses would be appropriate for the `<address>` tag, assuming it would be reasonable for people to want to contact both the client and the webmaster regarding the content of the page.

You wouldn’t include the copyright message in the `<address>` tag though, as it isn’t contact information.

Answer (score 2):

The page's owner is your client. All copyright is his. So I think address should refer to him.

Despite webmaster is a worker inside client's company, or an outside company, the information about webmaster is for ads reference only, and has no direct relation (as copyright is not his/her) with website purpose.