# How to mark the copyright of an image in html?

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-markup

this is a mostly semantic question. I want to put images with copyrights on the website. I know the figure and figcaption element, but figcaption doesn't seem the best tag for that. It's rather a caption which I also need.
If I've got an image like that:

```
<figure>
  <img src="img/content/preview.jpg" alt="Alttext für das Bild" />
  <figcaption>Caption goes here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Where do I put the copyright?

EDIT: The copyright text must be visible.

Comment: Do you want the copyright to be visible?

Comment: Yes, it's a requirement from our customer.

Comment: what about <address> ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683988/usage-of-address-tag-in-html-copyright-or-webmaster

Comment: I don't think <address> is the right choice here. In the specs it said: "The address element represents the contact information for its nearest article or body element ancestor" ([HTML5 SPEC](http://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html#the-address-element))
So it's not related to the image

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### In general

The copyright notice should be contained in a [`small` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/textlevel-semantics.html#the-small-element):

> […] typically features disclaimers, caveats, legal restrictions, or **copyrights**.

If the copyright notice applies to the content of a sectioning content element (e.g., `article`), include the `small` element in a [`footer` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sections.html#the-footer-element) that belongs to this sectioning element:

> A `footer` typically contains information **about its section such as** who wrote it, links to related documents, **copyright data**, and the like.

If it applies to the whole page, you might include the `small` element in a `footer` that belongs to the `body` (i.e. that is not nested in a sectioning element).

```html
<body>

 <article>
    <footer>
      <small><!-- if the license applies to the content of this article --></small>
    </footer>
  </article>

  <footer>
    <small><!-- if the license applies to the content of the whole page --></small>
  </footer>

</body>
```

#### When it contains a link to the license

If the copyright notice includes a link to a license (or to a page explaining the terms in more detail), use the [`license` link type](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/links.html#link-type-license), e.g.:

```html
<a rel="license" href="/license.html">Usage rights</a>
```

```html
<a rel="license" href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC BY-SA 3.0</a>
```

But note: this license will then apply (only) to **the whole main content** of the page (indicated by the [`main` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/grouping-content.html#the-main-element)).

#### In your case

`figure` is a [sectioning root](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sections.html#sectioning-roots) element, which means that `footer` (and `header`) can apply to it:

> The `footer` element represents a footer **for its nearest** ancestor sectioning content or **sectioning root element**.

So you could include a `footer` element (containing a `small` element) in the `figure`:

```html
<figure>
  <img src="img/content/preview.jpg" alt="Alttext für das Bild" />
  <footer><small><!-- copyright noice --></small></footer>
  <figcaption>Caption goes here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Structurally, this copyright notice would apply to the whole content of the `figure` element. (It’s also possible to include the `footer` in the `figcaption`.)

(And if you have a link to the license, only use the `license` link type if this `figure` is the main content and there is no other main content that should *not* be licensed under the same license.)

#### Leaving plain HTML: structured data

By using structured data (e.g., RDFa, Microdata), you can be more specific. This would allow to specify a different license for each piece of the webpage. [Example in this Webmasters SE answer.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/121902/17633)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the use of `<small>Your copyright text</small>` for this purpose.

From the [HTML spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element) on `<small>`

> The small element represents side comments such as small print.
>
> Small print typically features disclaimers, caveats, legal
>   restrictions, or **copyrights**. Small print is also sometimes used for
>   attribution, or for satisfying licensing requirements.

*Previously the `<small>` element was used to display a certain text with a smaller font, but nowadays all styling should be accomplished through CSS, and your HTML should only act as what the name suggest - markup.*

*Your browsers default stylesheet might still show the content of a `<small>` element with a smaller font-size though, so you might have to override that with your own CSS.*

Answer (score 2):

You should use `<small>` ([HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element)):

> Small print typically features disclaimers, caveats, legal
>   restrictions, or copyrights. Small print is also sometimes used for
>   attribution, or for satisfying licensing requirements.